# Choosing when to use a parametric or non-parametric test

Tags: nonparametric, mean, effect-size

I have some queries regarding using a non-parametric test, namely the Wilcoxon Sign Ranked test. I need to compare the means of pre- and post-intervention data. The data is being analysed as an overall composite score and then its relative sub-scales. Some of the sub-scales have passed tests of normality, therefore I’ll use a t-test, whereas others have failed. I am using the Shapiro-Wilk test for normality.

When investigating whether to do a parametric or non-parametric test, should I only be concerned with the results of the pre-intervention data’s normality test or do I need to consider the post-intervention data as well. My gut feeling is that the normality test of the post-intervention data would be irrelevant to this decision but I feel I need to check to be sure.

Second related question. If I go with a non-parametric test and wish to calculate the effect size, would this generally need to be $r$ and then converted to Cohen’s $d$?

Comment: It's not clear whether you are testing pre- and post- combined or separately for normality. In your last paragraph you don't define $r$. Using a t-test some of the time and not all the time depending on some arbitrary threshold for a normality test strikes me as a bit messy. A significant result at some conventional level for S-Wilk may just mean that your sample size is large enough to detect minor non-normality  that doesn't matter. When you are in doubt why not use both t-tests and Wilcoxon and flag if and when they give very different results? .

Comment: Hi Nick, Thanks for the reply. I ran the tests for normality for pre- and post- data individually. Should I have run them together? I hear what you're saying regarding chopping and changing between t-test and wilcoxon and it becoming messy. I was following my previous tutor's advice regarding what to do if the data fails tests of normality. I'll probably take your advice and report both. Regarding 'r', this is something I happened to come across when investigating calculating non-parametric effect sizes. I believe the info I have refers to 'r' as pearson's correlation